# What is the difference between exit() and exit_group()

Tags: linux, exit

What is the difference between [exit()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/exit) and [exit_group()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/exit_group). Any process that has multiple threads should use exit_group instead of exit?

To answer the question `why do you ask` - we are having an process that has around forty threads. When a thread is locked up, we automatically exit the process and then restart the process. And we print the backtrace of the thread that was locked up. We wanted to know whether calling exit in this case is any different from exit_group.

`From the docs: This system call is equivalent to exit(2) except that it terminates not only the calling thread, but all threads in the calling process's thread group` - However, what is the difference between exiting the process and exiting all the threads. Isn't exiting process == exiting all the threads.

Comment: According to the doc (and to experiment with `strace`), [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) is using `exit_group`

Comment: BTW, why do you ask? It actually only matters to `libc` implementors.

Comment: The C library's `exit` calls the `exit_group` system call. The `exit` system call only exits the calling process (and a process is a thread in kernel speak).

Comment: From the docs: This system call is equivalent to exit(2) except that it terminates not only the calling thread, but all threads in the calling process's thread group.

Comment: This isn't really a C question. exit_group() appears to be a *linux* system call, used from within the linux libc implementation. (I checked a freebsd system, and it's never heard of exit_group().)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I ask because, when we are facing an issue - we want to know whether the backtrace that we are seeing is the correct one on all the threads or is it incorrect because all the threads are not exited but abruptly terminated.

Comment: @ArlieStephens Removed the c tag and added only the linux tag.

Comment: @Linuxios Yes, I see that from the doc. But I’m not able to understand the subtle difference here. Anyway the process will be terminated. What does it mean that each thread will be terminated. Anyway exit will terminate the process, which is equal to terminating all the threads

Comment: Do you call `exit` (this is [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html)...) or `_Exit` (I believe you should not call it directly)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I call exit(3). But again, I’m trying to understand the difference here.

Comment: `_Exit` is a syscall. The library function `exit(3)` is doing some processing (calling `atexit` registered handlers & flushing stdio buffers) before calling `exit_group` or `_Exit` (you don't care which, trust your `libc`!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All thread libraries I know (e.g. recent [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)) are using the low-level [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) for their thread implementations (and some C libraries are even using `clone` to `fork` a process).

`clone` is a difficult Linux syscall. Unless you are a thread library implementor, you should not use it *directly* but only thru library functions (like e.g. [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)); see also [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html) used in [pthread_mutex](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock)`*` functions

The `clone` syscall is used to create tasks: either threads (sharing address space in a multi-threaded process) or processes.

The `exit_group` syscall is related to exiting these tasks.

In short, you'll never use *directly* [exit_group](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit_group.2.html) or `clone`. Your libc is doing that for you. So don't care about `exit_group` or `_Exit`; you should use the standard library function [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) only, which deals notably with [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) & [on_exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/on_exit.3.html) registered handlers and flushes `<stdio.h>` buffers. In the rare cases you don't want that to happen, use [_exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) (but you probably don't need that).

<sup>Of course, if you are reimplementing your own `libc` from scratch, you need to care about `exit_group` & `clone`; but otherwise you don't care about them.</sup>.

If you care about gory implementation details, dive into the source code of your `libc`. Details may be `libc`-version, *kernel*-version, and compiler specific!