# Why does a minimal binary call exit_group instead of exit?

Tags: c, gcc, system-calls, glibc

Content of `app.c`:

```
void main() {}
```

I execute `gcc app.c -o app -static -O3 && lurk ./app` to get:

```
execve("", "", "") = 0
arch_prctl(12289, 0x7FFFFFFFD430) = -22
brk(0x0) = 0x4C4000
brk(0x4C51C0) = 0x4C51C0
arch_prctl(4098, 0x4C4880) = 0
uname(0x7FFFFFFFD210) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/exe", ..., 4096) = 54
brk(0x4E61C0) = 0x4E61C0
brk(0x4E7000) = 0x4E7000
mprotect(0x4BD000, 12288, 1) = 0
exit_group(4200240) = ?
```

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/exit_group) of `exit_group` says:

> This system call is equivalent to exit(2) except that it terminates not only the calling thread, but all threads in the calling process's thread group.

However, no new threads were started by `app`, as can be seen in the traced sys calls. Why did `gcc` emit an unnecessary `exit_group` then, instead of `exit`?

Comment: Probably easier to just use it in the boilerplate code that calls `main()` than try to figure out if the program is using threads or not.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154256/what-is-the-difference-between-exit-and-exit-group

Answer (score 1):

In glibc the commit 8fabe0e632bd441c760f878d1022c378f04f8497 switches from `exit` to `exit_group` with the following commit message:

> Linux: Remove exit system call from _exit
>
> exit only terminates the current thread, not the whole process, so it is the wrong fallback system call in this context.  All supported Linux versions implement the exit_group system call anyway.